# SSRS Report Portal Management

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am working on an C# utility that would help clients publishing SSRS reports on their sites. Here my code:

```
public void createFolder()
    {
        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        // Create a custom property for the folder.
        Property newProp = new Property();
        newProp.Name = "Department";
        newProp.Value = "Finance";
        Property[] props = new Property[1];
        props[0] = newProp;

        string folderName = "Budget";

        try
        {
            rs.CreateFolder(folderName, "/", props);
            Console.WriteLine("Folder created: {0}", folderName);
        }

        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsAccessDenied</ErrorCode><HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus><Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' are insufficient for performing this operation.</Message><HelpLink xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsAccessDenied&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=13.0.1601.5</HelpLink><ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services</ProductName><ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">13.0.1601.5</ProductVersion><ProductLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId><OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">OsIndependent</OperatingSystem><CountryLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">1033</CountryLocaleId><MoreInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"><Source>ReportingServicesLibrary</Source><Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsAccessDenied" msrs:HelpLink="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsAccessDenied&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=13.0.1601.5" xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' are insufficient for performing this operation.</Message></MoreInformation><Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" />
```

Any idea?

Please note that a point of this exercise is not just get it work but knowing that it is going to run on a client side ideally without any tweaking on their part.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you [google the error](https://sqldude.wordpress.com/2008/12/24/the-permissions-granted-to-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied/)?  If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The article you are pointing to suggests going to Report Portal and adding a new role. And that is exactly what I am trying to avoid: having a client doing any manual work

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.  It sounds like you're not sure why you're getting a permissions error.  The answer is that you need to create a new role.  I **assume** (after your comment) that your question is how you can do that using C#.

You can use the [CreateRole() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createrole.aspx), which will only work with SSRS Native Mode.  If SSRS is installed in SharePoint Integrated mode, there is no supported method other than using the UI.

> This method throws an OperationNotSupportedSharePointMode exception
>   when invoked in SharePoint mode

Comment: I am looking into CreateRole() and not sure that is what I need. CreateRole() creates new role without relating it to a user/group. But in my case I need to add a user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' to the main folder and provide a role for it. That is what described in the article you pointed to. There is a method SetPolices(), but seems like it adds a user/group to a specific report, but I'd like to add 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' to the whole Report Portal. At least, that's how I understand it.